# how to get portal ids for taleo website like TUFTS university where portal id is hidden?use to generate RSS url

Tags: rss, jobs, taleo

Sites with Taleo have a fixed pattern to access RSS.
I have derived many RSS in this manner.
Example is https://merck.taleo.net/careersection/feed/joblist.rss?lang=en&portal=4540130092&searchtype=2&jobfield=2140130092&locale=en

I use these RSS feeds to populate my Job Portal Website at www.sjiauto.wordpress.com

but I came across a few sites like http://tufts.taleo.net/careersection/ext/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en
which hide the portal id in some variables so that their app only can use it. Is there any method to extract them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to view source in Google Chrome and find where it says "portal=" and the value for Tufts says "8240432407"

If the portal ID is hidden on one page source, it may be available if you click different links in the open portal page (like trying to sign into that portal & then viewing source, etc.)